# Showing modal view from UITabBar button press

Tags: swift, swift2, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have one button in my UITabBar that needs to show a modal (in Swift 2). I've searched and searched and tried some solutions but none of them worked. I recently found this link that makes it look straight forward: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-do-you-show-a-modal-view-controller-when-a-uitabbarcontroller-tab-is-tapped and am trying to follow it but to no avail.

My Initial View Controller is a my Main Table Bar Controller of `class MainTabBarController: UITabBarController`. In it's `viewDidLoad()`, I added the code (I think the link may have been using an older version of Swift so I had to make some syntax changes from the stuff in the link): `self.tabBarController?.delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? UITabBarControllerDelegate`.

I then added `UITabBarControllerDelegate` to my AppDelegate.swift and implemented the following in AppDelegate.swift, I also tried putting it in MainTabBarController but it also didn't work:

I want to point out that "CreateNavControllerViewController" is the root view controller to my "CreateViewController", which is what I want to display. But I have my middle tabbar button linked (the default TabBarController to View link) to the CreateNav which then is the rootVC of Create. In the modal I want to have a Navigation Bar at the top which is why I want to present CreateNav.

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    print("inside shouldSelect VC")
    if viewController is CreateNavControllerViewController {
        print("    viewController is CreateNavControllerVC")
        if let newVC = tabBarController.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CreateNavController") {
            print("        if let newVC = ...")
            tabBarController.presentViewController(newVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return false
        }
    }
    print("skipped everything, returning true")
    return true
}
```

None of the print statements print out. So I'm pretty stumped. Can anyone offer a solution for how to get one button in a UITabBar to present a view modally in Swift 2?

**Edit:** changed (shouldSelect viewController:) to (shouldSelectViewController viewController:) but still nothing. Just does the normal tabbar view change instead of a modal, doesn't print anything (function doesn't get called)

**Edit2:** I think I got it figured out, set the VC my tabbar shows initially to inherit from `UITabBarControllerDelegate` then added that function and in viewDidLoad() set `self.tabBarController?.delegate = self`. This seems to be working now

Answer (score 1):

You should change

`self.tabBarController?.delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? UITabBarControllerDelegate`

with

`self.delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? UITabBarControllerDelegate`

in your `UITabBarController`

Comment: still not working, can't figure out for the life of me what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Is your controller nested in a navigation controller? If so you should check if the first view controller of the navigation controller is a specific controller.